# Почему при запуске System.Threading.Timer в Windows Service служба заканчивает работу после нескольких итераций?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, таймер

Простой пример: служба, которая каждую секунду выполняет некоторую операцию, например записывает в лог-файл.

```
public partial class ProcessingService : ServiceBase
{
    private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public ProcessingService()
    {
        logger.Info("Service is started ... ");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        TimerCallback timerCallback = new TimerCallback(ProcessPaymentRequest);
        Timer timer = new Timer(timerCallback, null, 0, 1000);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(object obj)
    {
        logger.Info("Listening ... " + DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

При запуске служба делает несколько записей и заканчивает работу без ошибок.

Подскажите, с чем может быть связана такая проблема?

Сейчас мне кажется, что мне нужно как-то остановить основной поток выполнения OnStart() и тогда таймер продолжит работу.

Comment: У вас `timerCallback` и `timer` создаются локально, вынесите их в класс.

Comment: Я вот тоже думаю, что сборщик мусора удаляет локальный экземпляр таймера. Следует сделать его полем (так же, как `logger`).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Действительно. Спасибо вам и Геннадию!